# Marketing cloud - reuse footer in multiple email

Tags: marketing-cloud

In the marketing cloud project I just enter in, many email use the same footer,
inside the email content there is a query to a data extension and some of the retrieved data are displayed inside the footer.
Any time we have to change it, we would need to open each email and make the same change.
I wonder if there is a better way to do that, for instance reusing it, is there a way to create the footer code and link it inside each email?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle footers, headers and other repeating elements which can be part of multiple emails, is creating one Content Block with the footer, header or the element that you need and referencing it by using one of the AMPscript Content functions:

- ContentBlockByID
- ContentBlockByKey
- ContentBlockByName

That way you won’t have to update it in each email separately every time, as this function will be resolved at send time only.

Here’s more details on the above functions:

https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyid/

https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbykey/

https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyname/